# math.sin incorrect result

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(68)
-0.897927680689
```

But `sin(68) = 0.927` (3 decimal places)

Any ideas about why I am getting this result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do trigonometric functions give a seemingly incorrect result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77585408/why-do-trigonometric-functions-give-a-seemingly-incorrect-result)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`math.sin` expects its argument to be in radians, not degrees, so:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(math.radians(68))
0.927183854567
```

For reference, see `help(math.sin)`: "Return the sine of x (measured in radians)."
Or the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sin): "Return the sine of *x* radians."

Answer (score 0):

by default angle in Python is calculated in radians. So, you can try to multiply the angle (degrees) by 0.01745 - to convert it to degrees and input the values.

```
>>> print(math.sin(60*0.01745))
0.8659266112878228
```

Comment: This is very inaccurate: the correct value is 0.8660254037844386, so your result is wrong from the 4th decimal on. This gets even worse with large values of the angle: `math.sin(100*360*0.01745)` returns -0.118.., while it clearly should return 0. So don't do that, use the `math.radians` function to do the conversion, as explained in the accepted answer.