# Why do trigonometric functions give a seemingly incorrect result?

Tags: language-agnostic, trigonometry, degrees, radians

When attempting to use a trigonometric function in my programming language, I get a seemingly wildly incorrect result.

For example,

```
sin(90) = 0.8939966636005579
```

But I would expect `sin(90)` to be `1`. Similar things happen for other trigonometric functions.

What is going on and what can I do to fix this?

---

<sub>This is intended to be a canonical question for input unit requirements in trigonometric functions. ([related discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427373/do-duplicates-of-sin-cos-tan-expect-radians-instead-of-degrees-needs-to-match?cb=1))</sub>

Comment: You mean `sin(π) = 1.22460635382238E-16`

Comment: "*Why do trigonometric functions give a seemingly incorrect result?*", they are expecting the correct unit to be used, which [depends on the language](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27201/programming-languages-that-used-degrees-in-trig-functions). Note most of the time, trigonometric functions are not part of the language, but are provided by external libraries, which have the same constraint on the unit.

Comment: @Justine Krejcha, `sin(90) = 0.8939966636005579` is because `90` is 90 radians and not 90 degrees as well answered below.  If argument is in degrees, perform argument reduction (`fmod(d, 360)`) [or the like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502120/sin-and-cos-give-unexpected-results-for-well-known-angles/31525208#31525208) _before_ converting to radians to get better answers.  e.g. `sin(fmod(360090.0, 360)*1.5707963267948966192313216916398)`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

## Why is this happening?

Trigonometric functions generally expect units in [*radians*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), while `90` is in [degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)).

This also applies for other functions such as cosine and tangent, not just the sine function.

Most programming languages require trigonometric functions to provide their arguments in radians. This simplifies many things, especially on the implementation side as code may interface with [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math#Trigonometric_functions), which is standardized to expect that its arguments to the trig functions in radians.

It also happens to be that the radians are used very commonly in math as they are a natural unit for angle measurement. [This Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1797756/) and the answers there go into more detail.

Some programming languages may provide facilities to make the conversion in its standard library. For example, in Python this is provided by the [`math.radians`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.radians) function. The trigonometric functions themselves generally also say what format they expect their inputs to be in.

```py
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(math.radians(90))
1.0
```

This is the case in some programming language's standard libraries, such as [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f64.html#method.to_radians), [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians-double-), [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.radians), [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deg2rad.html), and others.

However, many programming languages don't provide facilities to [convert degrees to radians or back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135909), but an implementation is easy. You can do so by creating a function like so :)

```
PI = 3.1415926535897932; // or your programming language's standard library's pi constant

function toRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * (PI / 180);
}
```

After you've converted from degrees to radians, you can then call the trigonometric functions and get the answers you're expecting.

## What are some examples that I can use?

It is helpful to consult your programming language's standard library and documentation to see if a function for conversion exists in your programming language before writing your own.

### Languages that include a standard library function

[python](/questions/tagged/python) ([trig function docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions) | [conversion function docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.radians), see also [How can I convert radians to degrees with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875964/how-can-i-convert-radians-to-degrees-with-python))

```py
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(math.radians(90))
1.0
```

[java](/questions/tagged/java) ([trig function docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)* | [conversion function docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians-double-))

```java
System.out.println(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90.0)));
```

[matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) ([trig function docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/trigonometry.html) | [conversion function docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deg2rad.html))

Use the functions suffixed with `d`, which take degrees as an argument directly. For example

```matlab
sind(90)
```

You can also use the `deg2rad` function if you need to convert degrees to radians.

### Languages that don't include a standard library function

[c](/questions/tagged/c) ([trig function docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math#Trigonometric_functions))

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double deg2rad(double degrees) {
    return (M_PI / 180) * degrees;
}

int main() {
    printf("%f", sin(deg2rad(90.0)));
}
```

(Note: Not all implementations define `M_PI`, although many do, including [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mathematical-Constants.html) which says it comes from Unix98 and 4.4BSD. If yours doesn't, you'll need to define it.)

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ([trig function docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math#Trigonometric_functions))

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <numbers>

double deg2rad(double degrees)
{
    // `std::numbers::pi` is `double`, for `float` use `std::numbers::pi_v<float>`.
    return (std::numbers::pi / 180) * degrees;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::sin(deg2rad(90.0)) << '\n';
}
```

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) ([trig function docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=net-8.0)*, see also the Remarks sections on the docs for [`Sin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sin?view=net-8.0#remarks), [`Cos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.cos?view=net-8.0#system-math-cos(system-double)), [`Tan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.tan?view=net-8.0#system-math-tan(system-double)))

```cs
using Math;

public static double DegreesToRadians(double degrees)
{
    return (Math.PI / 180) * degrees;
}

public static int Main() {
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(90.0)).ToString());
    return 0;
}
```

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) ([trig function docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)*, specifically the [Converting between degrees and radians](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math#converting_between_degrees_and_radians) section, see also [How can I get sin, cos, and tan to use degrees instead of radians?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705123/how-can-i-get-sin-cos-and-tan-to-use-degrees-instead-of-radians))

```js
function degToRad(degrees) {
  return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
}

console.log(Math.sin(degToRad(90)));
```

<sup>* This programming language doesn't group their trig functions together in their documentation. Look for functions named `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, or similar.</sup>

Comment: For C at least, since the standard `sin` function uses `double`, not `float`, so should your `deg2rad` function. You could also introduce `deg2radf` (using `float`) and `deg2radl`(using `long double`) by analogy with the trig functions.

Comment: Fixed the type, thanks :)

Comment: 3.1415926535 has unnecessary rounding error for that number of digits. 
 The next digit is an 8, so you should round up instead of truncating. 
 Or use more digits since that's still less precision that a 64-bit `double`. 
Truncating at 3.1415926535897932 gives the same `double` as using more digits.  (I used GDB's `print` command, like `print (double)3.14...`)

Comment: Fixed. I decided to just add more precision to the constant.

Comment: For Matlab, you’d want the trig degree functions, like ‘sind’ and ‘cosd’ instead of manually converting degrees to radians.

Comment: For C, maybe you can add a `#ifndef M_PI` `#define M_PI ...` so that the code works whether or not the constant is provided by the library

Comment: Any reason you didn't mark this answer community wiki? This is a trivial answer but you managed to make multiple mistakes, instead of having people ping you in the comments, let them fix and enhance this answer for you. As of now, this answer is way below the quality level that was once required on this site and canonical QA should be community wiki anyway.

Comment: It is more common to define a _constant_ `deg = pi/180` such that typing `90*deg` would result in `pi/2` in radians.

Answer (score 4):

The results you're getting is very accurate. There is really no question of accuracy here. The problem is simply the use of degrees where the function expects radian. For your example of sin(90), 90 in radian can easily be converted to degrees by doing the following,

90/2pi = 14.3239

now subtract from 90 the value of 14*2pi to zero in on the sin wave that 90 radians places you in,

90-14*2pi = 2.0354 radians.
convert this to degrees

2.0354*180/pi = 116.62 degrees.
and finally
using your calculator calculate sin(116.62) = 0.894 which is the results that you got.